# SVN branch of a branch

Tags: svn, branch

Our code repository includes:
* trunk,
* branch A - starts from trunk,
* branch B - starts from branch A,

The programer that works on branch A wants to reintegrate it into the trunk, and continue working on the trunk only.

We do not want to reintegrate branch B into branch A yet.

Is it possible to have branch B relate to the trunk, instead of to branch A, so that the two programmers can continue to work separately on trunk and on branch B?

(I hope my question is clear)

Comment: Shouldn't the trunk be release code only typically so everyone would then have a working base!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I see it, you have following situation:

[image: pic1]

And you are going to do merge from **A** to **trunk**:

[image]

As you see, **B** has started from **A** and has its content. It cannot be changed to start from another codebase because it already exists. All you can do is merge changes from **trunk** to **B** after you have merged changes from **A** to **trunk**. In this case branch **B** will have actual content of both **trunk** and branch **A**:

[image]

Comment: And if I do this, I can later reintegrate branch B to the trunk, counting on mergeinfo?

Comment: Another question: I keep merging from branch A into branch B. So, if branch A is integrated into the trunk, and then I merge from trunk into branch B, won't it cause duplicate changes?

Comment: Answer is simple. If you're on Subversion > 1.5, then you can definitely count on mergeinfo in both cases you've desribed.

Comment: Well, I tried this now and it didn't work: after the merge from A to trunk, I tried to do a merge from trunk to B, and got a lot of conflicts - SVN tried to merge lots of changes that I already merged from A to B.

For example, in branch A, there were some new files. I merged from A to B, and the files went to B. Now, after the merge from A to trunk, I merged from trunk to B, and SVN tried to add the files again - causing a tree conflict ("local add, incoming add upon merge").

Comment: **that I already merged from A to B** you should not have done this. problem is that you didn't mention your merges from A to B neither in the initial question nor in comments. everyone probably would warn you not to do this. what I can recommend is exclude all changes made by merges from A to B, commit this version into B, and then try again to merge from trunk to B.

Answer (score 0):

Both trunk and all the branches are just some folders with some files in them. You are allowed to merge anything with anything else. So, the answer is that there's no exact concept of "relation", but one is not actually needed.

Comment: AFAIK only purpose of mergeinfo is to avoid merges that are already done, so that user can merge without thinking about revisions. It's a convenience tool. I usually merge exact revisions that haven't been merged before, so I have no use of mergeinfo. If I'm wrong someone please stop me!