# How to merge a branch-of-a-branch directly to trunk

Tags: svn, branch

Our project has a "trunk".

I worked on Branch A, adding several features, and kept merging changes from "trunk".

Now, my work on Branch A is complete, and I would like to start working on new features.

However, the manager of the trunk does not want to reintegrate-merge Branch A back to trunk yet.

What should I do?

- I can start a new Branch B directly from trunk, but then I will not have my features from Branch A.
- I can start a new Branch B from Branch A, but then I won't be able to reintegrate-merge my new features from Branch B directly to the trunk (I tried this on a sample file and there were too many conflicts).

What is the best practice for this scenario?

Our server is SVN 1.6.

(NOTE: this is not identical to [SVN branch of a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665878/svn-branch-of-a-branch) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should then wait for integration of branch A as long as you integrated branch B into A

In SVN there is a simple rule to keep yourself insane while merge:

**Merge only from and into your branch Source**(best is use  integrate option)

All other methods(cross merging, cherry picking,..) create in the (near?) future some headache