# Branching a Feature Branch with Subversion

Tags: svn, merge

I am trying to work with multiple feature branches as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665878/svn-branch-of-a-branch).  The difference is this question, and most of the others I have found, all have to do with older versions of Subversion and/or Tortoise.  I have version 1.9.7 of both Subversion and Tortoise.  It seems some significant changes were made starting with version 1.8.  For example, the "reintegrate" option seems to be deprecated or at least discouraged.

I (unknowingly) followed the same steps as the other poster and ran into the same issues.  I created branch A from branch B and constantly merged the trunk into A and then A into B with no problems.  That is, until I merged A back into the trunk - at that time I got a bunch of tree conflicts.  I also got errors trying to merge subsequent trunk changes into branch B after branch A had been merged.

So now I have branch B, which is in QA and not ready to merge into the trunk, and need to start on a new feature.  I thought maybe this time I should create branch C from the trunk and merge branch B into branch C, making C more or less equivalent to B.  However, if I try to merge B into C I don't get any new files.  I only get the changes to B that pertain to files already existing in the trunk.

I can't believe what I am trying to do is out of the ordinary or that it should be that complicated.  Can someone please explain to me how the branches should be originally created and what options I need to take when merging the branches between each other and/or into the trunk?

Comment: The deprecated `--reintegrate` option should not affect you, since this means only that a reintegrate will be automatically detected. From where did you create your branch B? And why did you not create a branch A from the trunk as well and then transfer changes from B to A?

Comment: The first time I created branch A from the trunk and then created branch B from branch A.  In the end this resulted in the tree conflicts.  So the next time I created branch C from the trunk (branch B still exists) but can't merge all of the changes from branch B into branch C.